# How to input text in a textarea in gwt

Tags: java, gwt

I am new to GWT and have made 3 textarea objects and have added them to a vertical panel, which is also added to my rootpanel. However, I cannot seem to input any text in these textareas. Any suggestions?

```
VerticalPanel panel = new VerticalPanel();
TextArea tb = new TextArea();
TextArea tb1 = new TextArea();
TextArea tb2 = new TextArea();
panel.add(tb);
panel.add(tb1);
panel.add(tb2);
RootPanel.get().add(panel);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try enabling them:

- `tb.setEnabled(true)`
- `tb1.setEnabled(true)`
- `tb2.setEnabled(true)`

But I don't think that should be necessary.

There might be something small you are missing, I would compare all of your code to [this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/gwt/text-input-example/).  It seems to be a good working example that you could compare your code to and see if you missed a small step.

It seems you may need to add the TextArea objects to horizontal panels and then add those horizontal panels to the vertical panel.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I actually put the textboxes in a flextable and then added that to the verticalpanel. I did this because I wanted to format my textboxes and put them in the right coordinates. However, this still doesnt let me click on any of the textboxes

Comment: ok. it may be that you need to add some event handlers to these in order for them to do anything?  [This example](http://www.karmicbee.com/gwt-textarea-with-max-character-limits/) may be what you are looking for, the key here being the `addValueChangeHandler` method call of the `TextArea` object (their example is making a subclass of `TextArea`, but it's still relevant.

It's common to make a `new ValueChangeHandler<String>()` or other type inline, but since you have three textboxes doing the same thing you may want to instantiate one `ValueChangeHandler<String>()` and add it to all three.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe maybe caused by adding another widget on top of your TextArea widgets. In this case TextArea widget may remain visible, but it will be unusable.

I don't see it in the code snippet that you provided, but maybe it's not all of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It is the example straight from the GWT Javadoc.

Maybe you need to use setCharacterWidth(int size) and setVisibleLines(int size) before adding it.

```
    public class TextBoxExample implements EntryPoint {

        public void onModuleLoad() {

        //Make an 80 x 50 TextArea
        TextArea ta = new TextArea();
        ta.setCharacterWidth(80);
        ta.setVisibleLines(50);

        // Add them to the root panel.
        VerticalPanel panel = new VerticalPanel();
        panel.add(ta);
        RootPanel.get().add(panel);
      }
    }
```